# Comprensión de listas en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, bucle-for

Estoy recorriendo dos listas a la vez por comprension de listas, pero quiero que en la primera lista vacia,`New = []`,  me queden los elementos que se encuentran en la lista `dos` (en efectivo eso lo logro) pero quiero que en la lista vacia `trash = []` me quede solo aquello  que no se encontró en la busqueda sobre la lista `dos`.

Lo que me queda al hacer `print` es un montón de cosas repetidas en el `trash` solo quiero lo que necesito.

**Este es mi código:**

```
uno = [u'Hitch_neck_01_proxy', u'Hitch_head_proxy', u'Hitch_chest_proxy', 
       u'Hitch_spine_04_proxy',u'Hitch_spine_03_proxy', u'Hitch_spine_02_proxy',
       u'Hitch_upperarm_r_proxy', u'Hitch_lowerarm_r_proxy', u'Hitch_upperarm_l_proxy',
       u'Hitch_lowerarm_l_proxy', u'Hitch_hips_proxy', u'Hitch_upperleg_l_proxy',
       u'Hitch_lowerleg_l_proxy', u'Hitch_upperleg_r_proxy', u'Hitch_lowerleg_r_proxy',
       u'Hitch_foot_l_proxy', u'Hitch_toes_l_proxy', u'Hitch_foot_r_proxy', 
       u'Hitch_toes_r_proxy', u'Hitch_hand_l_proxy',]

dos = [u'Hitch_neck_01_Target', u'Hitch_head_Target', u'Hitch_chest_Target',
       u'Hitch_spine_04_Target']

#--------------------------------------------------
trash = []
new = []

for x,y in [(x,y) for x in uno for y in dos]:
    if x[0:-6] in y:
        new.append(x)
    elif x[0:-6] not in y:
        trash.append(x)

print(trash, " <--- elementos no en la lista")
print(new, " < --- esta es la nueva lista")
```

**Salida:**

```
['Hitch_neck_01_proxy', 'Hitch_neck_01_proxy', 'Hitch_neck_01_proxy',
 'Hitch_head_proxy', 'Hitch_head_proxy', 'Hitch_head_proxy', 
 'Hitch_chest_proxy', 'Hitch_chest_proxy', 'Hitch_chest_proxy', 
 'Hitch_spine_04_proxy', 'Hitch_spine_04_proxy', 'Hitch_spine_04_proxy', 
 'Hitch_spine_03_proxy', 'Hitch_spine_03_proxy', 'Hitch_spine_03_proxy', 
 'Hitch_spine_03_proxy', 'Hitch_spine_02_proxy', 'Hitch_spine_02_proxy', 
 'Hitch_spine_02_proxy', 'Hitch_spine_02_proxy', 'Hitch_upperarm_r_proxy', 
 'Hitch_upperarm_r_proxy', 'Hitch_upperarm_r_proxy', 'Hitch_upperarm_r_proxy',
 'Hitch_lowerarm_r_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerarm_r_proxy','Hitch_lowerarm_r_proxy',
 'Hitch_lowerarm_r_proxy', 'Hitch_upperarm_l_proxy', 'Hitch_upperarm_l_proxy',
 'Hitch_upperarm_l_proxy', 'Hitch_upperarm_l_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerarm_l_proxy',
 'Hitch_lowerarm_l_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerarm_l_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerarm_l_proxy',
 'Hitch_hips_proxy', 'Hitch_hips_proxy', 'Hitch_hips_proxy', 
 'Hitch_hips_proxy', 'Hitch_upperleg_l_proxy', 'Hitch_upperleg_l_proxy',
 'Hitch_upperleg_l_proxy', 'Hitch_upperleg_l_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerleg_l_proxy',
 'Hitch_lowerleg_l_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerleg_l_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerleg_l_proxy',
 'Hitch_upperleg_r_proxy', 'Hitch_upperleg_r_proxy', 'Hitch_upperleg_r_proxy', 
 'Hitch_upperleg_r_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerleg_r_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerleg_r_proxy',
 'Hitch_lowerleg_r_proxy', 'Hitch_lowerleg_r_proxy', 'Hitch_foot_l_proxy',
 'Hitch_foot_l_proxy', 'Hitch_foot_l_proxy', 'Hitch_foot_l_proxy',
 'Hitch_toes_l_proxy', 'Hitch_toes_l_proxy', 'Hitch_toes_l_proxy', 
 'Hitch_toes_l_proxy', 'Hitch_foot_r_proxy', 'Hitch_foot_r_proxy', 
 'Hitch_foot_r_proxy', 'Hitch_foot_r_proxy', 'Hitch_toes_r_proxy', 
 'Hitch_toes_r_proxy', 'Hitch_toes_r_proxy', 'Hitch_toes_r_proxy', 
 'Hitch_hand_l_proxy', 'Hitch_hand_l_proxy', 'Hitch_hand_l_proxy', 
 'Hitch_hand_l_proxy']  <--- elementos no en la lista

['Hitch_neck_01_proxy', 'Hitch_head_proxy', 'Hitch_chest_proxy',
 'Hitch_spine_04_proxy']  < --- esta es la nueva lista
```

Comment: Hola Nestor. La verdad es que está bastante poco claro lo que preguntas. Parece que busques la intersección de conjuntos, pero esta es vacía. Veo que eliminas los 6 últimos caracteres de la lista `uno`, pero así y todo sigue siendo vacía. Intenta por favor explicar el problema en pseudocódigo para que sea más comprensible qué quieres hacer, en lugar de enseñar qué has hecho.

Comment: @fedorqui tienes razón y es lo más correcto, de hecho la iba a añadir pero entre la edición y el reetiquetado se me pasó...  Ya está reetiquetada, gracias por el aviso, saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla ¡gracias a ti por el curro de tener la etiqueta tan limpia y con tan buenas respuestas!

Comment: Nestor dices usar Python 2 pero esa salida es propia de Python 3, el `print` en Python 2 no daría esa salida usando ese código. Por favor, aclara que versión usas realmente, es importante porque no hay compatibilidad total entre amba

Comment: uso python 2.7 porque es para autodesk maya, pero la salida era del jupiternotebook de python 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que pretendes es crear dos listas a partir de `uno`, una con los elementos que están en `dos` y otra con los que no están te estas complicando sin razón. Usando `any` para recorrer tu lista dos buscando el substring puedes simplificarlo bastante:

```
trash = []
new = []

for x in uno:
    if any(x[0:-6] in item for item in dos):
        new.append(x)
    else:
        trash.append(x)

print 'Lista trash:\n', trash
print '\nLista new:\n', new
```

Salida:

```
Lista trash:
[u'Hitch_spine_03_proxy', u'Hitch_spine_02_proxy', u'Hitch_upperarm_r_proxy', 
 u'Hitch_lowerarm_r_proxy', u'Hitch_upperarm_l_proxy',u'Hitch_lowerarm_l_proxy',
 u'Hitch_hips_proxy', u'Hitch_upperleg_l_proxy', u'Hitch_lowerleg_l_proxy',
 u'Hitch_upperleg_r_proxy', u'Hitch_lowerleg_r_proxy', u'Hitch_foot_l_proxy',
 u'Hitch_toes_l_proxy', u'Hitch_foot_r_proxy', u'Hitch_toes_r_proxy',
 u'Hitch_hand_l_proxy']

Lista new:
[u'Hitch_neck_01_proxy', u'Hitch_head_proxy', u'Hitch_chest_proxy', 
 u'Hitch_spine_04_proxy']
```

No debes usar un segundo `elif` negando la condición del `if`, si el `if` no se cumple este `elif` va a ser siempre cierto, usa un `else` en su lugar.

Código válido para Python 3, solo usar `print` como función:

```
print ('Lista trash:\n', trash)
print ('\nLista new:\n', new)
```

Comment: lo resolvíd e una manera similar, pero el any() esta bastante interesante tu mtodo practico y rapido, de verdad muchas gracias! ya que estamos en estas te pregunto otra cosa,  supongamos que tengo listaA y listaB, cada una con X cantidad de items en ella por ejemplo 10 items en una y 10 en otra, donde cada item es una str y quiero comprobar si una palabra o mas de el string de se esta iterando concuerda con alguna palabra de la otra lista? comprobación de indice por indice de la str? alguna idea? gracias!!

Comment: por ejemplo: para ser mas claro, se esta iterando en el bucle en este momento "hitch_L_upperleg_main" con "L_upperleg_forTest", ambas comparte la palabra upperleg y la letra L , lo cual quisiera que eso fuese un match para luego agregarlo a un diccionario o lista en consecuencia

Comment: tal vez podria hacer algo dentro del bucle para que la str principal sea split("_") y me cree una lista en la iteracion, donde el elemento de la otra lista va a chekear si comparte dos o mas palabras o items de esa lista creada para hacer el match , ngo la idea pero se me va un pocoo

Comment: @NestorColmenares Si te he entendido bien tu idea es correcta, puedes usar `split` para dividir la cadena en palabras  usando `_` como separador. Si quieres saber si alguna palabra de una esta en otra basta con usar interseccion de conjuntos: `repetidas = set("hitch_L_upperleg_main".split('_'))&set("L_upperleg_forTest".split('_'))`. Esto retorna un set con las palabras repetidas en ambas cadenas: `{'L', 'upperleg'}`

Comment: lo he realizado de la siguiente manera :

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que eliminar cinco caracteres de "proxy" in seis de "Target", y dependiendo del tamaño de esas listas usar un dictionario/set que es mas eficiente:

```
dos_set = set([x[:-6] for x in dos])

new   = [x for x in uno if x[:-5] in dos_set]
trash = [x for x in uno if x[:-5] not in dos_set]

print "Lista trash:\n", trash
print "Lista new:\n", new
```

Comment: ¿Y si directamente usas la intersección de conjuntos con `dos_set & uno_set`?

Comment: Podrías hacerlo pero eliminarías duplicados, no se si es lo que el busca.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo que necesitas es los valores repetidos en las dos listas sin contar el el sufijo proxy o target.

```
unox = [data[0:-6] for data in uno]
dosx = [data[0:-7] for data in dos]

new = list(set(unox) & set(dosx))
print new
```

Lo cual imprimirá

```
[u'Hitch_neck_01', u'Hitch_head', u'Hitch_chest', u'Hitch_spine_04']
```

Answer (score 0):

al que le interese, he resuelto y la cuestion que necesitaba asi:

- de esta manera puedo tener una clase *DicttionaryMaker()* que a base de dos listas me genera un diccionario, con el metodo *Match* y me negera la lista *residuo* con el metodo *NotMatch* para tener un control amplio en todo lo posible, incluso tengo una *tolerancia* predefinida en 2 palabras minimo para meterlas en el diccionario.
- esto puede ser util en mi caso para trabajar en Autodesk Maya donde viene bien tener control de todos los elementos en escena.

gracias a los que contribuyeron !

```
chekingList = [u'Hitch_neck_01_proxy', u'Hitch_head_proxy', u'Hitch_chest_proxy',
u'Hitch_spine_04_proxy',u'Hitch_spine_03_proxy', u'Hitch_spine_02_proxy',
u'Hitch_upperarm_r_proxy', u'Hitch_lowerarm_r_proxy', u'Hitch_upperarm_l_proxy',
u'Hitch_lowerarm_l_proxy', u'Hitch_hips_proxy', u'Hitch_upperleg_l_proxy',
u'Hitch_lowerleg_l_proxy', u'Hitch_upperleg_r_proxy', u'Hitch_lowerleg_r_proxy',
u'Hitch_foot_l_proxy', u'Hitch_toes_l_proxy', u'Hitch_foot_r_proxy',
u'Hitch_toes_r_proxy', u'Hitch_hand_l_proxy','nestor_colt_02_nes','maria_perez_04_vie',
'juan_carlos_lara_curso','referendum_julio_jodido']

checkerList = [u'suck_neck_01_target', u'suck_head_target', u'suck_chest_target',
u'suck_spine_04_target',u'suck_spine_03_target', u'suck_spine_02_target',
u'suck_upperarm_r_target', u'suck_lowerarm_r_target', u'suck_upperarm_l_target',
u'suck_lowerarm_l_target', u'suck_hips_target', u'suck_upperleg_l_target',
u'suck_lowerleg_l_target', u'suck_upperleg_r_target', u'suck_lowerleg_r_target',
u'suck_foot_l_target', u'suck_toes_l_target', u'suck_foot_r_target',
u'suck_toes_r_target', u'suck_hand_l_target',]

#---------------------------------------------------------------------# 
class DictionaryMaker:
    import re
    # __INIT__
    def __init__(self,listA=None,listB=None):
        self.listA = listA
        self.listB = listB

    # Must Pass first the list what you want as KEYS
    # Then pass the list that you want as VALUES
    # It Has FIXEDVALUE for TOLERANCE

    def Match(self,listA,listB,fixedValue=2,match=True):
        dictionary = {}

        for x,y in [(x,y) for x in listA for y in listB]:
            def BreakWord(x):
                list2Check = x.split("_")
                pattern2Check = '(?:' + '|'.join(list2Check) + ')'
                regex = r'(?:\b|_){}(?=\b|_)'.format(pattern2Check)
                find = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
                resultado = find.findall(y)            
                return len(resultado)

            counter = BreakWord(x)

            if counter >= fixedValue:
                dictionary[y] = x

        # makes the residue list for further use
        residue = []
        copyListA = listA[:]
        copyListB = listB[:] 
        dicKey = dictionary.keys()
        dicVal = dictionary.values()

        for f in copyListA[:]:
            if any(f in vl for vl in dicVal):
                copyListA.remove(f)
        for m in copyListB[:]:
            if any(m in ky for ky in dicKey):
                copyListB.remove(m)

        residue.extend(copyListA)
        residue.extend(copyListB)

        # condition with the match flag        
        if match:
            for k,v in dictionary.items():
                # print the dictionary Created for debugging
                print ("{} < -- is key from : ---- >> {}".format(k,v))
            print (" ")
            return dictionary

        if not match:
            for x in residue:
                # print the residue from the searching
                print (" {} < -- residue ...  NOT MATCH  ".format(x))
            print ("   ")
            return residue

    def NotMatch(self,listA,listB,fixedValue=2):
        return self.Match(listA,listB,fixedValue=fixedValue,match=False)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

dict = DictionaryMaker()
DicForTestResult = dict.Match(chekingList,checkerList)
residueFromItems = dict.NotMatch(chekingList,checkerList)
```